# Run JavaScript if key pressed != ENTER

Tags: javascript, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

Im working on a MVC4 site, and I have a webgrid with a search textbox. My Textbox is inside a form, which will be submitted when I press enter. I also have a onkeypress script bound to the textbox, that will, after 3 sek, update my webgrid with what else is entered.

My problem is, that I only want to run the script if not the last key pressed is Enter.

My code looks like this:

```
                    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Filter", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "projects" }))
                {  
                    <div class="paddingTextToleft">
                        Search:
                        <input id="searching" name="searchString" type="text" value="" onkeypress="return keypressed()">


                        <p class="error">@ViewBag.SearchMessage</p>

                    </div>
                    <br />
                }
```

And the script:

```
 var timeoutReference;

function keypressed() {
    if (window.event.keyCode == 13) {
        //Do not run the script!
        return true;
    }
    else {
        if (timeoutReference) clearTimeout(timeoutReference);
        timeoutReference = setTimeout(function () {
            var value = $("#searching").val();


            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Filter", "Project")',
                contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'html',
                data: { searchString: value },
            }).success(function (result) {
                $('#projects').html(result);
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
};
```

I want it to stop the script (or not run the rest of it), if the key pressed is enter.

Hope anyone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: what is the problem with this?

Comment: The problem was that if I pressed Enter, it would call a form, which would update the view. And when the view was updated, the textbox was refreshed. But the key listener was still called, but reacted to an empty text field then.
But I fixed it by making it all a Ajax responsive with a keyup listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you are not sending Event to the function.
Call it with some parameters e.g:

```
<input id="searching" name="searchString" type="text" value="" onkeypress="keypressed(e)">
```

Then accept this event in a function:

```
var timeoutReference;

function keypressed(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    //Do not run the script!
    return;
}
else {
    if (timeoutReference) clearTimeout(timeoutReference);
    timeoutReference = setTimeout(function () {
        var value = $("#searching").val();


        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Filter", "Project")',
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { searchString: value },
        }).success(function (result) {
            $('#projects').html(result);
        });
    }, 3000);
}
```

};